# Electron Angular2 PouchDB

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, pouchdb

I am thinking of using Angular2, PouchDB and Electron for my desktop application. But I couldn't find a way to consume the PouchDB APIs from Angular2. Can somebody please help me how to use the PouchDB APIs in Angular2 as a service?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think a good resource are the [PouchDB Docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides) ... the basic steps seem to be the following:

Install the package with npm

```sh
npm install pouchdb
```

Import the Javascript file in your `index.html`:

```html
<script src="node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

In your Service:

```js
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
var db = new PouchDB('database name');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Preserver application I have build in Electron, Angular2 and PouchDB

Application [www.hiteshbalar.com/preserver](http://www.hiteshbalar.com/preserver)

Github Repo https://github.com/hsbalar/Preserver